# How to transparent UIImage gradually?

Tags: objective-c

I have a small UIImage, I want to make it become solid at the center, and transparent gradually forward to the border ? Anyone has a good idea on this? 
Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

At least two of the ways you could accomplish this are:

1. Create a series of images with the varying opacity in them. Then animate the UIImage by showing them in sequence.
2. Use a similar technique but use mask images. This involves using a series of images as a mask for your original image. Then animate the UIImage by redrawing it repeatedly using a different mask image each time to achieve the effect you want. See [CALayer mask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask).

The second may be preferred because it will work with any image and allows you to change the image without having to generate the animation for it or load the image dynamically.